# SQL adding only two columns with the same data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to add an administrator and a date into an column but I can only have two administrators per year, how do I do that?
I have this:

```
PROCEDURE regista_administrador (
    proprietario_in         IN administra.proprietario%TYPE,
    ano_in          IN administra.ano%TYPE)
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT ano INTO ano_in FROM administra WHERE (ano = ano_in);

    IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,   -- Código definido pelo programador.
                              'Já existem dois administradores nesse ano.');
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO administra(proprietario, ano)
           VALUES (proprietario_in, ano_in);
    END IF;
   EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
  END regista_administrador;
```

Comment: Why not declare a variable "ct" (for COUNT) in your procedure, and `select count(*) into ct from administra where (ano = ano_in)`? Then test for `ct > 1`. Let the database do as much of the work as possible!

Answer (score 0):

why do you select into input parameter?

```
SELECT ano INTO ano_in FROM administra WHERE (ano = ano_in);
```

You need to have another variable to SELECT COUNT and then check it:

```
 SELECT count(1) INTO ano_cnt FROM administra WHERE (ano = ano_in);

IF (ano_cnt = 2) THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,   -- Código definido pelo programador.
                          'Já existem dois administradores nesse ano.');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want have only 2 registered admin per year change this condition :

```
IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN
```

to

```
 IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1) THEN
```

to raise your error

And why you do this query ?

```
SELECT ano INTO ano_in FROM administra WHERE (ano = ano_in);
```

I think the right query is :

```
SELECT count(ano) FROM administra WHERE (ano = ano_in);
```

Comment: The test should be for >=2  (or >1); if there are two admins already, the procedure should raise an error, because the procedure is trying to insert one more admin for the same year.